# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a error with page updating

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::PagesController#update 
Page(#64407864) expected, got String(#17069256)
app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb:36:in `update'

line 36 of Admin::PagesController update

```
   if @page.update_attributes(params[:page])
```

page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :related, :class_name => "Page", :join_table => "pages_related", :foreign_key => "page_id", :association_foreign_key => "related_id"

end
```

_form.html.erb

```
    <%= f.select :related, Page.all.delete_if {|p| p.id == f.object.id}.collect {|p| [p.title, p.id]}, { :include_blank => true }, {:multiple => "multiple"} %>
```

**up:**

---

thanks, its working, but now Ive got the error with new Page creating

> Called id for nil, which would
>   mistakenly be 4 -- if you really
>   wanted the id of nil, use object_id
>
> Extracted source (around line #70):
>
> 70:   <%= f.select :related_ids,
>   Page.all.delete_if {|p| p.id ==
>   f.object.id}.collect {|p| [p.title,
>   p.id]}, { :include_blank => true },
>   {:multiple => "multiple", :class =>
>   "select_multiple"} %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `select` field should be called `related_ids`, since it will be passing back the IDs for the selected objects, not the actual objects themselves.

Comment: thanks, its workimng, but Ive got problem with Page creating now^) see code above